# How do i insert the value of the primary key into a insert query

Tags: php, mysql

How do I retrieve the value of the primary key in customer_information table, such that I could input the value into the INSERT statement to store data into my customer_payment_information table?

I thought of calling the value of the primary key and store it in a variable, such that I could input the variable into my INSERT statement to store data for my customer_payment_information table.

Unfortunately, nothing is being stored in my database.

This is my code:

```
$sql = "SELECT customer_id FROM customer_information ORDER BY customer_id DESC LIMIT 1";
if ($conn->query($sql)){
    $compile = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO customer_payment_information (customer_id, fullName, creditcardNumber, expiry, ccv) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");            
    $compile->bind_param("issss", $sql, $ccname, $ccnumber, $expdate, $ccvnumber);
    $compile->execute();
    $compile->close();
    $conn->close();
} else {
    $errorMsg = "Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error;
}
```

The primary key of TABLE 1 has auto_increment, hence the SQL query

"SELECT customer_id FROM customer_information ORDER BY customer_id DESC LIMIT 1"

TABLE 1:
[TABLE 1 FORMAT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wrdvy.png)

TABLE 2:[TABLE 2 FORMAT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pEAUz.png)

Comment: Is this a live site? You appear to be storing vital credit card information.

Comment: You don't appear to have executed the SELECT query. Did you check for errors at all?

Comment: No it is not a live site, plus I have encrypted the information so the credit card details stored in the database is encrypted.

Comment: Execute the first query, get the result and then bind it to the second query

Comment: Sorry my bad, I have updated the code. But my table 2 is not being stored of any data.

Answer (score 0):

You need to execute your inital select statement and get the result. Something like this should do it for you.

```
$sql = "SELECT customer_id FROM customer_information ORDER BY customer_id DESC LIMIT 1";
$customerQuery = $conn->query($sql);
$customerResult = $customerQuery->fetch_assoc();
$customerId = $customerResult['customer_id'];

$compile
    = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO customer_payment_information (customer_id, fullName, creditcardNumber, expiry, ccv) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
$compile->bind_param("issss", $customerId, $ccname, $ccnumber, $expdate, $ccvnumber);
$compile->execute();
$compile->close();
$conn->close();
```

You may want to consider something like `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()` after insertiing a record to get it's id for further use.